# Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead

Tags: laravel, vue.js

please help here my Form.vue code

```
<template>
<div v-if="alert.message" :class="['alert alert-' + alert.type]">
  <p>{{ alert.message }}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div :class="['form-group', 'label-floating',{ 'has-error' : errors.city}]">
       <label class="control-label">Kota</label>
       <select @change="city" v-model="state.city" class="form-control" required>
         <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.kota_id">{{city.kota_nama}}</option>
       </select>
       <span v-if="errors.city" class="label label-danger">
       {{ errors.city[0]}}
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div :class="['form-group', 'label-floating',{ 'has-error' : errors.profile}]">
       <label  class="control-label">Tahun</label>
       <select @change="profile" v-model="state.profle" class="form-control" required>
         <option v-for="profile in profiles" :value="profile.profile_id">{{profile.profile_tahun}}</option>
       </select>
       <span v-if="errors.profile" class="label label-danger">
       {{ errors.profile[0]}}
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

i'm so confused, with my error... i try to change v-show and still get error like

```
Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means anything you place inside `<template></template>` should be done so inside another element.

So, always create one div inside those tags like:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <!-- put all your code here -->
  </div>
</template>
```